# How can I check if a variable exists in Java?

Tags: java, null, primitive

I want to write to a variable only if there isn't anything already there. Here is my code so far.

```
if (inv[0] == null) {
    inv[0]=map.getTileId(tileX-1, tileY-1, 0);
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null
```

Comment: `inv[]` looks like an `int` array and `int` type being a primitive type, cannot be null.

Comment: int cannot be null, its a primitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming `inv` is an `int[]`.

There's no such concept as a value "existing" or not in an array. For example:

```
int[] x = new int[5];
```

has *exactly* the same contents as:

```
int[] x = new int[5];
x[3] = 0;
```

Now if you used an `Integer[]` you could use a null value to indicate "unpopulated"... is that what you want?

Arrays are always filled with the default value for the element type to start with - which is `null` in the case of reference types such as `Integer`.

Answer (score 9):

inv is an `int[]`, and `int` cannot be `null`, since it is a [primitive](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and not a reference. 

`int`s are initialized to zero in java.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. The primitive `int` is initialized to zero only if it has class scope.  An int declared in a method (or more restrictive scope) remains uninitialized.

Comment: @Paul, a new array of int values will all be zero.  To be precise regarding regular local int variables, they need to be initialized before use due to the rules of [Definite Assignment](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/defAssign.doc.html#25979).  The java compiler will prevent compilation of uninitialized-before-use local variables.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that `inv` is an `int[]`. You can't compare an `int` to `null`, `null` only applies to reference types, not primitives. You have to either assign it some kind of flag value instead (`0` being popular, and the value it will have by default when you create the array), or make `inv` an `Integer[]` instead (`Integer` being a reference type, it is `null`-able).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming from error message, that `inv[]` is array of `int`, and `int` in java is not an object, so it cannot have `null` value.. You have to compare it with `0` (default value on each index of empty int array)..

Comment: Unless 0 is a valid value for him.  He should explicitly initialize the array to a value he knows is invalid.

Comment: Of course, you're right, but I did expected that from the code.. The code is short and almost meaningless..

Answer (score 0):

A primitive can not be null in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Well... `int` is a primitive type. That can't be null.

You can check the size of the array:

int[] arr = new int[10];
   System.out.println( arr.size() );

The plain arrays are indexed from 0 to their size - 1, and no value can be missing.
So in your code, you are asking whether the first member of type `int` is `null`, which can't happen - either it's a number or it will cause `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

If you want to have a "sparse array" similar to what PHP or JavaScript, you need a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
map.put( 1, 324 );
if( map.get( 2 ) == null ) ...
```

Comment: Isn't this autoboxing?  (Perhaps worth a mention.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
Integer[] inv = new Integer[10];
inv[0] = 1;
inv[1] = 2;
    ....

if(inv[3] == null)
{
    inv[3] = getSomeValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `inv` is an array of `int`, not the object wrapper `Integer`.  Your array comes initialized for you anyway.  If you wrote

```
int[] inv = new int[5];
```

you will have an array of 5 zeroes.

You should initialize your array yourself using some value that you know is invalid (e.g. if you had an array of ages, a negative value would be invalid).  Check for the invalid value and if it's there, replace it.

Answer (score -1):

primitive types can't be compared to null.

You can test if the number if > 0 to see if a value exists:

```
if(inv[0] <= 0)
{
    inv[0]=map.getTileId(tileX-1, tileY-1, 0);
}
```

Comment: The OP is placing tiles on a grid, or at least he appears to be. (0,0) is at the top left corner of the grid so all of the points are positive. So yes -3 is technically a value, just not valid for this.

Comment: so inv is an array meant to contain a tileid for a specific location. I see nothing saying -3 can't be an identifier for a tile